# Exception generated after exporting code as runnable jar

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

> D:\RhythmFileDownload>java -jar fileDownload.jar
>   Starting ChromeDriver 2.28.455520 (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b
>   port 36946
>   Only local connections are allowed.
>   Apr 03, 2017 6:14:23 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake c
>   on
>   INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true
>   ote end
>   Apr 03, 2017 6:14:23 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake c
>   on
>   INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Sou
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(
>   der.java:58)
>   Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: no such session
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455520 (cc17746adff54984afff48013673
>   4b),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86) (WARNING: The server did not
>   ny stacktrace information)

Comment: How did you create the runnable jar file? Please have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150811/what-is-a-fat-jar

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with IE driver. I was able to resolve it by downloading the latest driver and updating the browser to the latest version.

Try after updating your Chrome browser and downloading the latest chromedriver. Also, make sure that you download the Chrome driver according to your machine i.e. 64 bit/32 bit.

Comment: I changed my browser to Internet Explorer.

Comment: No luck with Chrome. with latest chromedriver and chrome browser. It runs in IDE but doesnt run as Jar.